# UITableView not scrolling, Only 11 rows displayed based on screen size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to display an array of strings in a table format. Following method gets called only 11 times, (the screen gets filled with 11 rows):

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyTableCell = @"MyTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyTableCell];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyTableCell];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.MyArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

My array has 20 strings but only 11 are getting displayed on the screen(I'm running this on simulator). There is no scroll bar coming up for the table. The screen is stuck with just 11 rows. in my XIB i just have this tableview alone, nothing else. Can somebody help me, thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the - tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method. Is it returning

```
[self.MyArray count];
```

Also bare in mind that using mouse's scroll wheel doesn't work in the simulator. You have to click and drag to simulate scroll.

Comment: you know what !!! problem was with the way I was scrolling !!! I had to click and drag, thanks a lot man !!! I'm actually too new to this whole system. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Also do you know why the table view is not responding to the arrow keys in keyboard. It is working only through click and drag. Do i have to enable something to make it work ? ??

Comment: Does iPhone have keyboard with arrow keys? :) (You can't do on simulator more than on real device)

Comment: Happy to help. Like nicael said no arrow keys anyway on a touch device.